# Orchestra testbench could not be found

Tags: laravel, composer-php, phpunit

I have currently a problem with testing a new laravel package. For a better testing environment I would like to use Orchestra's techbench. I follow the whole installation guide. At the moment my PhpStorm IDE could not find the testbench package but it is included in the vendor directory. I guess it's some autoloading problem but I can't find the mistake.

I tried to install the package with:
`composer require --dev "orchestra/testbench=^3.5"`

composer.json

```
 "require-dev": {
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0@dev",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.2|^7.0",
        "orchestra/testbench": "~3.5.0",
        "orchestra/database": "~3.5.0"
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: So after a bit research I tried to run Orchestra with phpunit directly. Phpunit can resolve the correct class. I guess it is some problem with my PhpStorm. Maybe my package must be reindexed or something else with PhpStorm.